# Cannot read Excel file from SQL Server with multiple versions of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, openrowset

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

USE [master] 
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

Reading Excel

```
DECLARE @SQLconnect VARCHAR(8000)

SET @SQLconnect =  'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                       ''Excel 8.0;Database=D:\WAGES.xlsx;'', 
                       ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]'')'
                       EXEC (@SQLconnect)
```

Exception

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Sometimes it gives error sometimes it goes in infinite loop of execution.

> **NOTE:** I am getting this error after installing SQL Server 2008 R2 over SQL Server 2012.

- OS: Windows 7 32-bit
- SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 installed

Comment: Have you tried just executing that directly, not in inside dynamic SQL? Any reason you are using dynamic SQL? IS `D:\WAGES.xlsx` on the SQL Server?

Comment: I have tried both way. And yes Wages.xlsx on D:\ and SQL Server on same machine

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server Error Message if a user have no rights for SQL Server TEMP directory:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "Unspecified error".
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

**Grant rigths to TEMP directory**
(i.) This step is required only for 32-bit SQL Server with any OLE DB provider

The main problem is that an OLE DB provider creates a temporary file during the query in the SQL Server temp directory using credentials of a user who run the query.

The default directory for SQL Server is a default directory for SQL Server service account.

If SQL Server is run under Network Service account the temp directory is like:

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp
```

If SQL Server is run under Local Service account the temp directory is like:

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Microsoft recommends two ways for the solution:

> A change of SQL Server TEMP directory and a grant of full rights for all users to this directory.
>       Grant of read/write rights to the current SQL Server TEMP directory.

See details: PRB: ["Unspecified error" Error 7399 Using OPENROWSET Against Jet Database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296711/EN-US)

Usually only few accounts are used for import operations. So we can just add rights for these accounts.

For example, icacls utility can be used for the rights setup:

```
icacls C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp /grant vs:(R,W)
```

For more information follow this [Link](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-distributed-queries.htm)

Comment: @Rajeshirke I answer based on your error message from this [link](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-distributed-queries.htm), I think the link can help you more.

Comment: Actually it was working when Microsoft SQL Server 2012 was installed, but problem is occurred after SQL Server 2008 R2 is installed over it..

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Select the SQL Server Services folder in the left pane.
3. Right-click the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service in the right pane.
4. Click Properties.
5. Click the Advanced tab in the properties dialog that pops up.
6. Add “-g512;” to the front of the value for parameter “Startup Parameters”.
7. Click OK.

Comment: Can you explain -g512 value?